# PostgreSQL: How to test if timestamp has timezone?

Tags: postgresql, datetime, timezone, timestamp-with-timezone

I would like to prevent that any timestamps without timezone are inserted in a PostgreSQL `SQL` function. The only approach I managed to come up with doesn't work because Postgres just seems to ignore any timezone string suffixes and instead uses the timezone from the server:

```
hostname:~ username$ date
Tue Sep 27 15:30:16 CEST 2016

hostname:~ username$ uname -a
Darwin hostname.domain 14.5.0 Darwin Kernel Version 14.5.0: Mon Aug 29 21:14:16 PDT 2016; root:xnu-2782.50.6~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

hostname:~ username$ psql -U postgres
psql (9.5.3)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# SELECT extract(TIMEZONE FROM '2016-09-19 01:00:00'::timestamptz);
 date_part
-----------
      7200
(1 row)

postgres=# SELECT extract(TIMEZONE FROM '2016-09-19 01:00:00+0200'::timestamptz);
 date_part
-----------
      7200
(1 row)

postgres=# SELECT extract(TIMEZONE FROM '2016-09-19 01:00:00+0800'::timestamptz);
 date_part
-----------
      7200
(1 row)
```

I have a feeling I'm generally misunderstanding something. Can anyone help ?

**Update 20160928:**

In order to give some explanatory context, this is my database (stripped down to what is essential for the question at hand):

```
CREATE DATABASE my_db;
CREATE TABLE my_table
(
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    timestamp_utc timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    title text NOT NULL
);
```

and this is my function to insert data in its current form:

```
CREATE FUNCTION insert_row
(
    p_timestamp_utc timestamp with time zone,
    p_title         text
)
RETURNS integer
LANGUAGE SQL
SECURITY DEFINER
VOLATILE
AS
$BODY$
    INSERT INTO my_table
                (  timestamp_utc    title)
         VALUES (p_timestamp_utc, p_title)
      RETURNING id;
$BODY$;
```

I have created an [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/6b6e6); creating the function there keeps failing though...

**The Problem:**

Calling the function succeeds even if the timestamp parameter does not carry a timezone:

```
SELECT insert_row('2016-09-01 01:00:00'::timestamptz, 'some title');
```

and I need to find a way to make this function call fail.

The reason *why* I need to make this fail is that I want the definition of what timezone any timestamps are in to be enforced by code; the alternative would be that both database server and client somehow implicitely / silently agree on a convention - and that does not really sound like a smart move to me...

Answer (score 1):

In PostgreSQL, timezone information is not stored along with the `timestamp with time zone`.
Rather, the timestamp is converted to [UTC](http://r.search.yahoo.com/_ylt=A0LEV1W5eepXWwQAqzJXNyoA;_ylu=X3oDMTBydWNmY2MwBGNvbG8DYmYxBHBvcwM0BHZ0aWQDBHNlYwNzcg--/RV=2/RE=1475013178/RO=10/RU=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FCoordinated_Universal_Time/RK=0/RS=.rACigFBOSH1eNuL6Iiqbhpi7cc-) when it is converted to its internal representation.

When a `timestamp with time zone` is converted to a string, e.g. when it is displayed, it is converted to the timezone that is set in the `TimeZone` configuration parameter.

The same happens when you use `EXTRACT` to retrieve the timezone information. The documentation is a bit unclear about that.

So if your timezone is set like this:

```
test=> SHOW TimeZone;
   TimeZone
---------------
 Europe/Vienna
(1 row)
```

You will get:

```
test=> SELECT extract(TIMEZONE FROM '2016-01-01 00:00:00-07'::timestamptz);
 date_part
-----------
      3600
(1 row)
```

because Central European Time is offset 1 hour from UTC, and

```
test=> SELECT extract(TIMEZONE FROM '2016-08-01 00:00:00-07'::timestamptz);
 date_part
-----------
      7200
(1 row)
```

because Central European Summer Time is offset 2 hours from UTC

Comment: Thanks for the info! :-) While your response is certainly informative, it doesn't really help me with my problem of preventing that any timestamps without timezone are inserted into my database, does it ?

Comment: I was trying to address your "general misunderstanding". To enable me to help you with your problem, can you explain what you mean by *inserted in a PostgreSQL `SQL` function*?